# How to take focus away from VF page?

Tags: visualforce

We have an app which requires a section with a VF page in it to be in the Page Layout. Unfortunately, this now automatically takes the focus to that section whenever a record is opened.

Is there a way to stop this from happening ? I guess I could do it by putting the focus to the first field. The only solutions I have been able to find have been showing how to put focus on specific fields within a VF page. But I don't even want to go to that VF page. I just want the Page Layout to open without jumping down to the section with the only VF page.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Visualforce causes the first field that is rendered on page load to gain focus. To avoid this usually favorable behavior, you can delay rendering any fields for a moment.

---

```
public class q370311 {
    public Boolean renderForm { get; set; }
    public q370311() {
        renderForm = false;
    }
    public void showForm() {
        renderForm = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="q370311">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!renderForm}">
            <apex:inputText label="Demo 1" />
        </apex:outputText>
    <apex:actionFunction name="showTheForm" action="{!showForm}" reRender="form" />
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    showTheForm()
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I actually never want the focus to automatically go to the VF page on the page. It is part of the app which may not even be used by the user. If possible I would like for the focus to just go to the first page on the page layout - and then if the user wants to use the VF page in that section he/she will just manually scroll to it and use it.

Comment: @Zoom_v That's kind of what I presumed you meant. Rendering the form afterwards should prevent the page from getting focus, I think.

Comment: just an fyi - I was unable to change the VF page because it's part of a managed package. So we ended up just taking it off the Details part of the page and putting it on a different tab. That prevented it from demanding the focus whenever somebody would open a record. Thanks again for your help.